# What is the precise definition of `f(E, V) = O(E + V)`?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What is the definition of `f(n) = O(n^2)`?
This means the following:
There exist `c > 0` and `n0` such that `f(n) <= c*n^2` for all `n >= n0`.

What is the precise definition of `f(E, V) = O(E + V)`?

Comment: What is `f(E, V)` here? There is no general notation for that, as it depends on E & V! I suggest you to read about [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: (E, V) -> f(E, V) is a two variable function.

Comment: So, you seem to have picked an example where a given function (which would surely be defined somewhere in your study reference, IMO) is having the complexity `O(E+V)`. But, as far as I know, it is not like that. Take an example, f(E,V) = E^2 + V^3 + 5, here the complexity can't be expressed as O(E+V).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really works in the same way in your case. One valid definition might be:

There exist c > 0 and n0 such that f(E, V) <= c*(E+V) for all E, V >= n0.

However, you can also define it differently, e.g. by introducing two variables *c, d > 0* and requiring *f(E,V) <= c*E + d*E*. Both are valid definitions.

However, most likely you have encountered this definition in the context of graph algorithms, where *E* is the number of edges and *V* the number of vertices. The time complexity *O(E + V)* occurs a lot in this field as it really is the same thing as saying *O(max(E, V))*. It is still linear time complexity.

Comment: Berthur, Thank you very much for your clear answer.